# Write custom emmet snippets with higher priority than default

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

How can I create custom emmet snippet with **the highest possible priority to display** in vscode?

When I updated `html.json` to add my own snippet for comment (with autor), I still see default emmet "c" snippet as first in list:

```
"Comment": {
    "prefix": "c",
    "body":[
        "<!-- atiris: $1 -->$2"
    ],
    "description": "Insert comment into html code"
}
```

That means I always have to choose the second option first.
**Is there any property / settings to prioritize my own snippets?**

[image]

Comment: Add this line in setting `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` ;)

Comment: Don’t you think it’s strange that they generally have priority as such?? Well, if I manually entered that c > comment, then when I press tab it should be inserted, regardless of what else is there about it
p.s. of course thnx and upwoted =*

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"

Or open settings, write 'snippets' in the search box, and select 'top' in Snippet Suggestions

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MmLJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BetterSnippets vscode extension](https://github.com/zardoy/vscode-better-snippets). It provides way more customization then builtin snippets. For your case you can use smth like this:

```json
"betterSnippets.customSnippets": [
  {
    "name": "c",
    "body": "<!-- atiris: $1 -->$2",
    "when": {
        "languages": [
            "html"
        ],
    },
    "sortText": "!1"
  },
]
```

`SortText` property is what you're looking for. I use `!1` to make snippets order more customizable e.g. if I would assing `sortText: "!2"` to other snippet it will appear under the snippet with `!1`

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the intellisense snippets with the above code rather than the Emmet snippets.

Regarding your question, the following link may help you prioritize which snippets are shown first: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32346

Regarding adding snippets to Emmet, the following should help:

In the settings.json file you can add the line
    "emmet.extensionsPath": "/Users/username/Documents/code snippets"
 (changing the path to a folder of your choosing)

Then add in that folder a file named snippets.json

You can use the format outlined in the link below to add snippets.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet